# Override NSTextField - mouseDown only fires once

Tags: swift, mouseevent, nstextfield

In my code I am overriding the `mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)` however am finding that the mouse down event only fires once, when the `NSTextField` becomes `firstResponder`

```
class GSTextField: NSTextField {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("in mouse down")
        return super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }
}
```

What I am ideally trying to achieve is to track the insert point on every mouse click. This is needed later in my code.

I think this has something to do wiht the field editor for the NSTextField doing the work behind the scenes.
Thanks
GS

Comment: The text field is the delegate of the field editor. You can subclass `NSTextField` and implement/override the methods of `NSTextViewDelegate` like `textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)`.

Comment: That worked - many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@willeke response gave me a workable solution
I moved form trapping `mouseDown()` to using `textViewDidChangeSelection()`

The question about why `mouseDown()` only fires once is still outstanding however I no longer need to resolve that.